# full calendar business hours(available date and time) set dynamically through date picker

Tags: datepicker, fullcalendar, availability

I'm using FullCalendar and datepicker to set the availability(date and time) for the user. Once the user click on date and time (I'm getting fromdate,todate,fromtime,totime) the area should be available to book appointments and the rest of the area should be grayed out and unavailable to book the appointments. I've tried every way mentioned in the full calendar docs also the ones mentioned here.How to pass the values selected in the date picker to the fullcalendar and set the availability? Any help would be appreciated ! thank you in advance!

Comment: please show what you tried specifically. That way we don't waste time duplicating work you've already done. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson hi,i'm trying to pass the dynamic values selected in the dropdown(fromdate,todate,fromtime,totime).
i couldn't do it with the business hours.so now trying to do with the events and here i couldn't do it with range of dates.

events: [
                   {
                     start: newfromdate,
                     end: newtodate,
                     rendering: 'background'
                   }
                   ],

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem from such a small sample of code, and without any data. Please add enough code into the question (not in the comments) so as to actually reproduce your issue. Possibly it's as simple as an issue with date formats or something but I have no way to know based on the info so far. Thanks